# Finding zero divisors of polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find a zero divisor, if possible, in each of the following. If not possible, explain why not.

a) $\Bbb Z_4[x]$

b) $\Bbb Z_5[x]$

The definition my book gave for zero divisors in this situation was that if we have $f(x) \in \Bbb Z_a[x]$ and $b \in \Bbb Z_a$ non zero, then $f(x)$ is a zero divisor if and only if $bf(x)=0$. And they do not really give any examples on how to use this idea. This is really confusing to me considering we are working with polynomials. So any help solving these problems and correcting my definitions/understanding is appreciated.

Comment: Any zero divisor in $\mathbb{Z}_4$ will also be a zero divisor in $\mathbb{Z}_4[x]$.  Can you find one in $\mathbb{Z}_4$?  Why can't you find one in $\mathbb{Z}_5$?

Comment: In a), $2\cdot 2=0$. In b) $\Bbb Z_5$ is a field so there are no zero divisors

Answer (score 1):

In a ring $R$, a non-zero element $a$ is a zero divisor if there exists a non-zero element $b \in R$ such that $ab=0$. So in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_4[x]$, elements like $2, 2x, 2(x+1), 2(x^2+3)$ will be examples of zero divisors.

Whereas in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$, since every non-zero element among $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is invertible, therefore you will not be able to find zero divisors. You should try to take a polynomial of the form $ax+b$ and then use the definition above to see the idea.

Comment: Could you explain why in the examples you gave for $\Bbb Z_4[x]$ that those are zero divisors? What element from $\Bbb Z_4$ would allow for $ab=0$?

Comment: @Nid the main thing is that $2 \cdot 2=0$. So $2$ is a zero divisor and because of this $2 \cdot 2x =4x \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$. Thus $2x$ is also a zero divisor.